# ASP.NET: C# or JScript?

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript

I love JavaScript. I started out coding in ActionScript and since the syntax is almost identical, I naturally understood JavaScript.

Recently, I have been learning how to use ASP.NET and MVC (which is not new to me since there are several MVC frameworks for Flash and Flex). And I'm trying to decide whether I want to learn C# or JScript... I say this ignorantly because I don't know how different JavaScript and JScript are... and C# is a completely different language all together.

1. What advantages does C# have over JScript?
2. and does it really even matter that I know and love JavaScript?

Comment: I think this question should have been community wiki

Comment: @Shimmy - I'm not sure "C# or JScript?" even really makes much sense in this context. I believe the correct answer is actually pretty objective since dcolumbus stated he'll be using ASP.NET MVC. "C# or VB.NET?" on the other hand is quite a bit more subjective.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't write ASP.Net in JScript.NET? I've never heard of anybody doing so, as there seems to be no support for it in VS, but I don't know that it can't be done.

Comment: JScript is still around?  I wouldn't touch it with a 100' pole.

Comment: @Terminal Frost, yes. Thank you for that. There is plenty of reading that I have already done on said Wiki's, but I wanted the perspective of those who already use the languages.

Comment: @Gabe, JScript.NET is the last think you wanna do now days, AFAIK it's not even supported in VS 2010, also Microsoft doesn't put any effort in this language at all (from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript_.NET "JScript.NET")).
Now to the OP's question, I think it's not a question of 'OR', the answer is simple "Yes, you should learn C# AND JScript", with more effort on the C# lang.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using ASP.NET MVC you're going to want to learn both C# and Javascript. Microsoft is now bundling jQuery, a Javascript framework, with Visual Studio and it is a great fit with ASP.NET MVC. I'd recommend using C# for the controllers and model layers, regular HTML for the view templates and then jQuery for all the client-side DOM manipulation.

**Edit:** Just noticed you said you already know and love Javascript. I'd just like to point out that I had never used Javascript before learning ASP.NET MVC and I found it to be a lot more similar to C# than I was expecting. Of course C# is statically typed, however the syntax has quite a few similarities.

Answer (score 3):

C# if only because you will be a gazillion times more employable.

Answer (score 2):

.NET in general and ASP.NET can be written in many languages, however only two are really popular and have big pool of support and tutorials: C# and VB.NET

This alone is reason enough to choose C# over JScript IMO, and C# share lots of its syntax with JScript - surely much more than VB.NET will ever share.

So like everyone already said, go with C# and you'll be swimming in familiar water with the bonus of many lifeguards available for you and ready to jump and save you when you drown. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. JScript is actually a script language used by Microsoft product. If you compare JScript over C#, it's somehow like you compare JavaScript with Java.
2. ASP.Net require full managed programming language like VB.Net or C# (I noticed that the role of Java.net is fading out, is it?), I don't think JScript is supported in most cases.

One more PLUS on C#: Learning C# isn't that hard suppose you have enough experience in OOP ActionScript. They share quite a number of common syntax, and quite importantly, most tutorials and resources out there about .Net is written in C#.

Comment: -1: From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2h4yzx6.aspx: "The primary role of JScript 10.0 is construction of Web sites with ASP.NET and customization of applications with Script for the .NET Framework. JScript 10.0 has features such as true compiled code, cross-language support through Common Language Specification (CLS) compliance, and access to the .NET Framework."

Comment: Remember, `JScript != JScript.NET`.

Comment: RPM1984: JScript.NET lost its .NET suffix several years ago, so unfortunately it seems that there is no longer any easy way to distinguish the CLR-based and browser-based languages. :(

Comment: @Gabe, I don't mean JScript cannot, but just a random search on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.aspx the code sample part for JScript is absent. I have no idea if it is really NOT supported nor Microsoft guys don't bother to document that. Either way, it feels somehow it is abandoned in CLR (or cause too less people use it in that way).

Comment: xandy: You're right that JScript isn't very well supported (though most of the examples existed all the way up through .Net 3.5 if you look at the "Previous Versions" link), but it's wrong to say that it's just a scripting language and not a full managed programming language like C# and VB.